# Can the Hebrew word qara (קָרָא) mean to rename?

Tags: hebrew, genesis

We see in Genesis 1:5 that God called the light as day and darkness as night. The Hebrew word used to translate this word is קָרָא. We see however that God was renaming something that already had a name. I have checked some Lexicons and did a word search through logos software but I never found the usage of this word as to rename. My question therefore is upon the usage and meaning of the word קָרָא if it can mean to rename.

Comment: There's a flaw in your logic. From the author's point of view there are two ways of referring to these things, but when God assigned the names day and night, they weren't already going by the names light and darkness. It's as though in a biography you read: "When he was born, Bono's parents gave him the name Paul." So the premise isn't sound. But aside from that point, yeah, I don't see why qara can't be used of something that already has a name -- though I suggest "call" or "christen" rather than "rename". When God outright replaces a name (Abraham, Israel) it's not used, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of kara is called. And in the context it is initiating the name, not renaming it.